# React PropTypes.shapes interdependence

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I declared two shapes:

```
export const parentShape = PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // ...someProps
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(childShape),
});

export const childShape = PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // ...otherProps
  parent: parentShape,
});
```

`parentShape` uses `childShape`, and `childShape` uses `parentShape`.

Now I have warning about `childShape` is used before its definition. How can I fix it?

Comment: A component should not have its proptypes definition defined in another component.

Comment: I just describe all commonly used shapes in one constant file. What kind of problems can I get?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable (`parentShapeProps`) with the props for `parentShape`, instead of passing it directly to `PropTypes.shape`, and then you can add `children` to `parentShapeProps` only after defining `childShape`:

```
const parentShapeProps = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // ...someProps
};

export const parentShape = PropTypes.shape(parentShapeProps);

export const childShape = PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // ...otherProps
  parent: parentShape,
});

parentShapeProps.children = PropTypes.arrayOf(childShape);
```

Comment: It works until I don't use `.isRequired`. If I use `.isRequired` I recieve:


"Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `parent` is marked as required in `childShape`, but its value is `undefined`."

Answer (score 0):

You can predifine `childShape` with `let`/`var`:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

let childShape;

const parentShape = PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // ...someProps
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(childShape),
});

childShape = PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // ...otherProps
  parent: parentShape,
});

export default { childShape, parentShape };
```

Comment: This decision forces me to use inconvenient export